# GoogleMap fragment or ImageView with map bitmap?(Perfomance)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

What is better in terms of perfomance: to use GoogleMap fragment provided by GMC or to use static image downloaded from web and set  into ImageView?

Comment: it depends on what you want to get

Comment: @andreich I want to get best performance and minimum heap consumption

Comment: Use Google Map Fragment...

Comment: Because if you are Using static image which is Downloaded from server.. Sometimes it takes Much time to load and in Google Map You can just get in Built control of BitmapDescriptorFactory..that's why.